# Why does GCD dispatch_async on main queue causes a deadlock from background queue?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I am creating a serial background queue like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t assetCreationQueue;

// in init...
_assetCreationQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.assetCreationQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Then I enumerate ALAsset objects in the background like this:

```
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    if (asset){
        dispatch_async(weakSelf.assetCreationQueue, ^{
            ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
            NSURL *url = [assetRepresentation url];
            if (url) {
                AVURLAsset *avAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

                // This NSLog fires! avAsset exists.
                NSLog(@"AVURLAsset %@", avAsset);

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // This NSLog NEVER fires.
                    // Also tried dispatch_sync.
                    NSLog(@"add to assets array on main queue");
                    [weakSelf.assets insertObject:avAsset atIndex:0];
                });
            }
        });
    }
}];
```

The assets array property is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *assets;
```

When I try `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` I only get ONE `NSLog(@"AVURLAsset %@", avAsset);` in the console and it indicates that `dispatch_sync` is causing a deadlock.

But how can I find out why? I don't see where. The assetCreationQueue is a background queue and I have to operate on the array only on the main queue.

**EDIT:**
Here is a much more simplified test which also fails:

```
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    if (asset){
        dispatch_async(weakSelf.assetCreationQueue, ^{
            if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                NSLog(@"already main thread"); // gets called often!!
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"dispatch async on main queue"); // never gets called!!
                });
            }
        });
     }
}];
```

So what I don't understand is: Why am I already on the main thread even though I call `dispatch_async(weakSelf.assetCreationQueue`. It can only lead to evil conclusion: The queue I create is NOT a background queue:

```
_assetCreationQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.assetCreationQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Why?

Comment: Can you double-check that your updated code is what you're actually testing? It's missing a parenthesis.

Comment: @RobNapier fixed. It got accidentally deleted while I tried to format it in the SO code editor. This is the code I am testing.

Comment: It looks like both your background queue and the main queue are one and the same.  Can you log out what `weakSelf.assetCreationQueue` returns with `NSLog(@"%p", queue);` to confirm/refute this?

Comment: Unfortunately I messed around a lot with this code since the post it is entirely different now. But it appears the AVAssetLibrary -enumerateAssetsUsingBlock method is using dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),...) which is causing a deadlock if I attempt to dispatch a block on the main queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Not really an answer, but I want to provide enough information to move forward.)

I've tried a very simple program, and this doesn't reproduce at all. I get many calls to "dispatch async on main queue" and no calls to "already main thread" (the opposite of what you're expecting). I'm running this on an iPhone 5. Complete code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@import AssetsLibrary;

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t assetCreationQueue;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  self.assetCreationQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.assetCreationQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

  ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  AppDelegate __weak *weakSelf = self;
  [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                         usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                           [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
                             if (asset){
                               dispatch_async(weakSelf.assetCreationQueue, ^{
                                 if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                                   NSLog(@"already main thread"); // gets called often!!
                                 } else {
                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                     NSLog(@"dispatch async on main queue"); // never gets called!!
                                   });
                                 }
                               });
                             }
                           }];
                         }
                       failureBlock:nil];
  return YES;
}
@end
```

Note that the use of `weakSelf` here is unnecessary and dangerous (but if this were the problem, you'd be crashing). You only need `weakSelf` if the block is going to be stored in a property of an object that `self` retains. It is not necessary or even desired for short-lived blocks like this. The way you've used it, if the owning object deallocated in the middle of the enumeration (which it can), `weakSelf` would become nil, `weakSelf.assetCreationQueue` would be `nil`, and `dispatch_async()` would crash. (But again, this is unlikely the cause of your issue, since it should crash.)

Comment: Thank you Rob but no luck. In my case all blocks called by the AVAssetLibrary enumerator execute on the main thread already. I did more testing and moved from a serial to a concurrent queue and figured out that when I call dispatch_sync(mainQueue,...), which calls dispatch_async(concurrentQueue,...), which either calls dispatch_async(mainQueue,...) or dispatch_sync(mainQueue,...), there is a deadlock.

Comment: You mean the above code, by itself, doesn't work on your device? What version of iOS are you running?

Comment: Oh, now I see!!!!! I don't know why or how, but all of a sudden your code worked perfectly on my iPhone 5 iOS 7. At first it seemed it hanged in a deadlock too. The culprit I think from my original code was there was a dispatch_async call that accidentally became a dispatch_sync. Because already main thread, dispatch_sync deadlocked it. Thank you x1000! Accepted your answer.